# Resetting the value of the variable for every new row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a query which would do the below options for me. I have been given a table(**testdata1**) say:

```
 YearS                    CountS($)
 2015                     360
 2016                     1000
 2017                     2000
 2018                     3500
```

From this table I have to create another table(**testdata2**) as listed below:

```
YearS                       NewCountS($)
2015                        360
2016                        640(i.e 1000 - 360)
2017                        1000(i.e. 2000 - 1000)
2018                        1500(i.e. 3500 - 2000)
```

There is one more thing which I need to keep in mind is that any number of row can be given to me in the **testdata1** therefore what I tried is:

```
set @diffr := 0;

update testdata1
set cd = (@diffr := CountS - @diffr)
order by yearS;
=================================
insert into testdata2(yearS, NewCountS)
Select yearS, cd
from testdata1;
```

This query works but generates this output:

```
YearS                       NewCountS($)
2015                        360
2016                        640
2017                        1360
2018                        2140
```

I found [**this**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56608/reset-variable-when-row-value-is-changed?newreg=c80f3e193a984e5cb2a654c62f3319ef) link to help but did not understood what the answer explains since I am tyro in `mysql`.
My query:

> 1. How to achieve the desired result?
> 2. Is there a better way to get the data from **testdata1** table to **testdata2** table(i.e. without creating **cd** column in **testdata1**)?

Any help will be heartily welcomed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to perform an UPDATE of `testdata1`. Just write a query that gets the rows you need to insert into `testdata2`.

If we want to use a user-defined variable, test the statement first to verify that it returns the result we expect.

```
SELECT r.years
     , r.counts
  FROM (
         SELECT s.years
              , s.counts - @prev_counts  AS `counts`
              , @prev_counts := s.counts AS `prev_counts`
           FROM ( SELECT @prev_counts := 0 ) i
          CROSS
           JOIN testdata1 s
          ORDER BY s.years
       ) r
 ORDER BY r.years
```

Note that the inline view `i` initializes the user-defined variable at the beginning of the statement, essentially equivalent to running a separated `SET @prev_counts = 0;` statement.

For each row, the value of the user-defined variable is set to the value of `counts`, so that it will be available when we process the next row. Note that we are expecting MySQL to do this assignment operation *after* the udv is referenced in the preceding expression.

Note that this behavior with user-defined variables used like this (the order of evaluation) is documented (in the MySQL Reference Manual) to be "undefined". We do observe consistent behavior with carefully constructed SQL, but we should make note that officially this behavior is not guaranteed.

Once the SELECT is tested, we can turn it into an `INSERT ... SELECT`.

An alternative that doesn't use a user-defined variable, we could use a correlated subquery in an expression on the SELECT list. (gain, write this is a a SELECT statement and test it first, before we turn it into an iNSERT ... SELECT)

```
SELECT q.years
     , q.counts
     - IFNULL(
               ( SELECT r.counts
                   FROM testdata1 r
                  WHERE r.years < q.years
                  ORDER BY r.years DESC
                  LIMIT 1
               )
       ,0) AS `counts`
   FROM testdata1 q
  ORDER BY q.years
```

---

**EDIT** to add explanation of the query above

starts out as a simple query like this:

```
SELECT q.years
     , q.counts
   FROM testdata1 q
  ORDER BY q.years
```

For each row returned from `testdata1`, the expressions in the SELECT list are evaluated, and a value is returned. In this case, the two expressions are simple simple column references, we get the value stored in the column.

We could use a more complex expression in the SELECT list, for examples:

```
SELECT q.years
     , q.years - 2000  AS `yy`
     , REVERSE(q.years) AS `sraey`
     , CONCAT('for ',s.years,' the count is ',s.counts) AS `cs`  
     , ...
```

The same thing happens for those expressions in the SELECT list, for every row returned, those expressions are evaluated, and a value is returned.

It's also possible to use a *query* as an expression, but with some restrictions. The query must return a single column (a single expression), and can return at most one row.

When the query is working on the row `years-2017`, the expressions in the SELECT list are evaluated.

The specification is that we want to get the value of `counts` for the preceding year, `years=2016`. We could get that row by executing a query like this:

```
 SELECT r.years
      , r.counts
   FROM testdata1 r
  WHERE r.years = '2016'
```

To use a query like this as an expression in the SELECT list, we need to make sure it doesn't return more than one row.  We can add `LIMIT 1` clause to ensure that it doesn't. And we need to return only one column ...

```
 SELECT r.counts
   FROM testdata1 r
  WHERE r.years = 2016
  LIMIT 1
```

But that always gets the `2016` row. What we can do now is change that to reference values from the row in the outer query, instead of the literal `2016`.

```
 SELECT (
          SELECT r.counts
           FROM testdata1 r
          WHERE r.years = ( q.years - 1 )
          LIMIT 1
        ) AS `prev_years_counts`
      , q.counts
      , q.years
   FROM testdata1 q
  ORDER BY q.years
```

Note that `q.years` in the subquery is a reference to the row from the outer query. When a row from `q` is being processed, MySQL executes the subquery, using the value of `q.years` in the WHERE clause. For each row processed by the outer query, the subquery is executed. And because of that `q.years` reference in the outer query, we say that its a *correlated* subquery.

In the event no row is returned (as will be the case for `q.years=2015`, the subquery returns a NULL value. We wrap that whole subquery in a `IFNULL` function, so if the subquery returns `NULL`, we will return a `0`.

And the end result is a value. We can write expressions in the SELECT list that do subtraction, e.g.

```
 SELECT q.counts - 540 AS `counts_minus_540`
```

In place a literal `540`, we can use expressions or column references ...

```
 SELECT q.counts - foo AS `counts_minus_foo`
```

We can use the correlated subquery expression in place of `foo`, just like we did in that second query in this answer, of the form:

```
 SELECT q.years
      , q.counts - IFNULL( crsq ,0) AS `counts`
   FROM ...
```

where `crsq` is the correlated subquery

```
 SELECT q.years
      , q.counts - IFNULL( 

          SELECT r.counts
           FROM testdata1 r
          WHERE r.years = ( q.years - 1 )
          LIMIT 1

        ,0) AS `counts`
   FROM testdata1 q
  ORDER BY q.years
```

With the given example data, this query is equivalent to the second one in the answer.  If there is z gap in the `years` values (for example, there is no `years=2016` row. the query result will be different, because the correlated subquery will return something different for `q.years-2017`.

Comment: First of all I would like to extend my sincere gratitude for the details you provided in the answer.The answer works for me. Thank you for helping me Sir(**@spencer7593**) in understanding the problem better